# Error WebGL useProgram: program not valid

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I have this code for webgl and i'm trying to compile and use this program, but when i make gl.useProgram();  i get this error: WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid.

I don't know how i can resolve this problem or if i have any error in vertexshader or fragmentshader.

```js
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#glCanvas");
    // Initialize the GL context
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

    // If we don't have a GL context, give up now

    if (!gl) {
        alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
        return;
    }
    
  
  // Vertex shader program
    const vsSource = `
    layout (location = 0) in vec4 VertexPosition;
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 TextureCoord;

    out vec3 Position;
    out vec3 Normal;
    out vec2 TexCoords;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uMVP;

    void main()
    {

        Position = vec3 (uModelViewMatrix * VertexPosition);
        Normal = normalize(uNormalMatrix * VertexNormal);

        TexCoords = TextureCoord;

        gl_Position = uMVP * VertexPosition;
    
    }
  `;


    const fsSource = `
    in vec3 Position;
    in vec3 Normal;
    in vec2 TexCoords;

    layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

    struct TMaterial {
        sampler2D Diffuse;
        sampler2D Specular;
        float Shininess;
    };
    struct TLight {
        vec3 Position;

        vec3 Ambient;
        vec3 Diffuse;
        vec3 Specular;
    };

    uniform TMaterial Material;
    uniform TLight Light;

    vec3 Phong(){
        vec3 n = normalize(Normal);
        vec3 s = normalize(Light.Position - Position);
        vec3 v = normalize(-Position);
        vec3 r = reflect(-s, n);

        vec3 Ambient = Light.Ambient * vec3(texture(Material.Diffuse, TexCoords));
        vec3 Diffuse = Light.Diffuse * max(dot(s, n), 0.0) * vec(texture(Material.Diffuse, TexCoords));

        vec3 Specular = Light.Specular * pow(max(dot(r, v), 0.0), Material.Shininess) * vec3(texture(Material.Specular, TexCoords));

        return Ambient + Diffuse + Specular;
    }

    void main()
    {
      FragColor = vec3 (Phong(), 0.0);
    }
  `;


    //Crear el programa y linkarlo a los shaders que acabamos de crear
    const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource);

    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);


    const programLightingMap = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(programLightingMap, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(programLightingMap, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(programLightingMap);


    gl.useProgram(programLightingMap);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebGL</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.2.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

    <script src="Shader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>WebGL!!</h1>
    <canvas id="glCanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <hr>
    <p id="diplayData"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
I get this erros of the shaders:

```
ERROR: 0:2: 'in' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:3: 'in' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:4: 'in' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:6: 'out' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:7: 'out' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:8: 'out' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
ERROR: 0:18: '*' : wrong operand types - no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uniform highp 4X4 matrix of float' and a right operand of type 'in highp 3-component vector of float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 0:18: 'normalize' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:18: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:18: 'assign' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'out highp 3-component vector of float'
```

Comment: At the very least you should check the result of shader compilation using `gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)` and likewise for the linker stage with `gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)`.

Comment: Thansk for answer, when i make >     
console.log(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS));
    console.log(gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS));
I get> 
false
false

Comment: And i get false for gl.getProgramParameter too

Comment: Please read [this link](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html).  It has a lot of useful info regarding how to check for compilation and link errors.

Comment: Hey! thank you, know i can get more information about it, i edit the post with the errors, i don't know what does it means really.

Comment: In case you are looking to learn WebGL2 , check [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/webgl-internals/?referralCode=6E7843BC98639EAB0377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors mean you're trying to use a WebGL2 shader in WebGL1

> 'in' : storage qualifier supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only

means you used `in` as in

```
in vec4 position;`
```

which is only valid in GLSL ES 3.00 and above just like it says

To make the shaer GLSL ES 3.00 the first line has to be

```
#version 300 es
```

But if do that you'll get a new error that `#version 300 es` is invalid in WebGL1

You have 2 options

1. Switch to WebGL2.

   Change your `getContext` call to use `webgl2` instead of `webgl` and then add `#version 300 es` as the first line of your shaders
2. Rewrite your shaders to use GLSL 1.0

   In that case tell work with WebGL1.

Also your line 18 needs to be something like

```
    Normal = normalize(mat3(uNormalMatrix) * VertexNormal);
```

or

```
    Normal = normalize((uNormalMatrix * vec4(VertexNormal, 0)).xyz);
```

Comment: Yes, it is that. Thank you!! and i add that i have to change too:
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");

Comment: Now i have other errors in line 18 of vertexshader and thats not depends of the version :/